# Creating a script to every x time click buttons on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, artificial-intelligence

(I am not looking for any code, just what I should search on google or programs to create it or any ideas)

I want to create a script that in a roulette page, gets what color was on the previous bet and presses a button to bet automatically, according to what color it was.

Thank you very much, anything will help.

Comment: search for something like "betting bot"

Answer (score 0):

I like your question, because it gives me the opportunity to clarify some aspects of computing which are normaly not known. At first, software for betting on a roulette game is not programmed with Javascript or jquery like the tags in the OP but with a programming language called "AutoIt". Thats a scripting language for Microsoft Windows which is a quasi standard for programming betting bots, aimbots and lots more of these things. The programming itself is done in a iterative way. The first step is to identify the buttons which have to be clicked with a function called pixelsearch, and than other sub-functions has to be created for determine the amount of bet and the order of placing actions. Most information about AutoIt in general and betting bots in detail are given in so called autoit forums. Sometimes the complete sourcecode is available and if not, the other guys will help for concrete questions. Also here in stackoverflow is a tag available called "autoit" for questions about concrete problems in that language.